# How to embed videos in Outlook or Thunderbird?

Tags: email, video, outlook, embed, thunderbird

Is it possible to embed Youtube videos in email messages in Outlook or Thunderbird so that the receiver can play the video inside of Outlook or Thunderbird?

(I dont want picture with hyperlink to youtube).

Thanks for hint or tip.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the embed code of Youtube. Then in Thunderbird, create an html-formatted message and go to Insert ->HTML, put your embed code there.

Most mail clients won't display anything, but some may do it. Thunderbird itself will not show it.

Comment: What do you mean by "the embed code of YouTube"? How do I get it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use third-party services like [viwomail](https://www.viwomail.com/en/) to generate a HTML template of your mail. They will do things like generating GIF/images(to be used in cases when email clients don't allow videos to play).
Next, you can use services like [Sendinblue](https://www.sendinblue.com/) to send HTML email.

Some of the email clients do not allow videos strictly. However, Apple mail client, outlook 16(only on MAC), Samsung native email app and some other clients do work for me.